# Outlook Rendering issues

Tags: c#, winforms, office-addins

I have a requirement wherein, I initiate the email from outlook, which uses an outlook add-in to create an template on a 3rd party mass email server, and then sends out the email to the recipients.

The problem is not creating the template on the 3rd party server, but is when it reaches outlook recipients, it doesn't render right. What is the best way to deal with such issues?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the community! This question needs more details so that a better answer can be generated. Please provide examples of how the emails are supposed to look, how they are coming out, and a code example of what you are doing now.

Comment: Issue resolved, this was taken care by the 3rd party. There was an issue on their side and the exchange firewall on our side was throwing it out of the window.